# Google Cloud Storage: Setting incorrect MIME-type

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a Node.js server running on a Google Compute Engine virtual instance.  The server streams incoming files to Google Cloud Storage GCS.  My code is here: [Node.js stream upload directly to Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830163/node-js-stream-upload-directly-to-google-cloud-storage)

I'm passing `Content-Type` in the XML headers and it's working just fine for `image/jpeg` MIME-types, but for `video/mp4` GCS is writing files as `application/octet-stream`.

There's not much to this, so I'm totally at a loss for what could be wrong ... any ideas are welcome!

**Update/Solution**

The problem was due to the fact that the `multiparty` module was creating `content-type: octet-stream` headers on the 'part' object that I was passing into the pipe to GCS.  This caused GCS to receive two `content-types`, of which the `octet` part was last.  As a result, GCS was using this for the inbound file.

Comment: Could you please post what your http request looks like? Are you sure that video/mp4 is really set as content type in the http request?

Comment: Can you confirm that this is multipart upload? In that case there should be multiple http requests sent out? Can you also provide http response headers and body for this request (and the other ones if there are any)?

Comment: @markovuksanovic My level-of-knowledge with a lot of HTTP is kind of low -- how can I verify that it is multipart?  Other info included above (console.log of the response from Google).

Comment: You can use wireshark to trace http. Make sure that you don't use HTTPS requests but HTTP only (just for testing purposes). You can also send me/share the capture file so I can have a look at what's happening.

Comment: @markovuksanovic Really appreciated -- problem is that the PUT request is being made by from the Google Compute Engine VM instance --> Google Cloud Storage ..... Separately, did you notice how the headers contained two separate content-types?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more information about the upload. Have a look and see if that fixes your problem. I think you're missing the X-Upload-Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looking at your HTTP request and response it seems like content-type is specified in the URL returned as part of the initial HTTP request. The initial HTTP request should return the endpoint which can be used to upload the file. I'm not sure why that is specified there but looking at the documentation (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload - start a resumable session) it says that X-Upload-Content-Type needs to be specified, along some other headers. This doesn't seem to be specified in HTTP requests that were mentioned above. There might be an issue with the library used but the returned endpoint does not look as what is specified in the documentation.

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload, "Example: Resumable session initiation request" and see if you still have the same issue if you specify the same headers as suggested there.

Comment: I think you might be reading the iana.org resource incorrectly; you'll notice you can't find either image/jpg or image/jpeg ... but those work fine.  I believe as long as the file type is listed in the table, then it is a valid ... and mp4 is listed under video.  I could be wrong though ...

Comment: Ok, you are right, video/mp4 should work for GCS correctly. I've tried manually uploading an mp4 video and it was assigned "video/mp4" mime type. In that regards you're right. Can you please provide your http requests that are being sent out?

Comment: Did you declare the content-type or did you just let Google decide?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage is content-type agnostic, i.e., it treats any kind of content in the same way (videos, music, zip files, documents, you name it).

---

But just to give some idea,

First I believe that the video () you are uploading is more or less size after it being uploded. so , it falls in `application/<sub type>`. (similar to section 3.3 of [RFC 4337](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4337.txt))

To make this correct, I believe you need to fight with storing mp4 metadata before and after the file being uploaded.

please let us know of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me in a similar situation is below. TLDR: Save video from web app to GCS with content type video/mp4 instead of application/stream.

Here is the situation. You want to record video in the browser and save it to Google Cloud Storage with a content type set to video/mp4 instead of application/octet-stream. User records video and clicks button to send video file to your server for saving. After sending the video file from the client to your server, the server sends the video file to Google Cloud Storage for saving.

You successfully save the video to Google Cloud Storage and by default GCS assigns a content type of application/octet-stream to the video.

To assign a content type video/mp4 instead of application/octet-stream, here is some server-side Python code that works.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_file(file_obj, rewind=True)
blob.content_type = 'video/mp4'
blob.patch()
```

Here are some links that might help.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33320634/19829260
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64274097/19829260

NOTE: at the time of this writing, the Google Docs about editing metadata don't work for me because they say to set metadata but metadata seems to be read-only (see SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/33320634/19829260)

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit