# Set metadata in Google Cloud Storage using gcloud-python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I am trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage using [`gcloud-python`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python) and set some custom metadata properties. To try this I have created a simple script.

```
import os

from gcloud import storage

client = storage.Client('super secret app id')
bucket = client.get_bucket('super secret bucket name')

blob = bucket.get_blob('kirby.png')
blob.metadata = blob.metadata or {}
blob.metadata['Color'] = 'Pink'
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Pictures/kirby.png'), 'rb') as img_data:        
    blob.upload_from_file(img_data)
```

I am able to upload the file contents. After uploading the file I am able to manually set metadata from the developer console and retrieve it.

I can't figure out how to upload the metadata programmatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We [discussed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/issues/1185) on the issue tracker and it surfaced a "bug" in the implementation, or at the very least something which catches users off guard.

Accessing `metadata` via `blob.metadata` is read-only. Thus when mutating that result via

```
blob.metadata['Color'] = 'Pink'
```

it doesn't actually change the metadata stored on `blob`.

The current "fix" is to just build up

```
metadata = {'Color': 'Pink'}
blob.metadata = metadata
```

Comment: I am trying to create and upload a blob with the Content-Disposition meta data to attachment. I've tried passing it using the above code, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: After setting the metadata as shown here, you must call `blob.patch()`. Then this works just fine for me.

Comment: @JoeRivera maybe by doing `blob.content_disposition = 'form-data'` solves your problem. By doing it directly against the `blob` instead using metadata attribute.

Answer (score 4):

```
blob.content_disposition = "attachment"
blob.patch()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blob.cache_control = "no-store"
blob.patch()
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-set-object-metadata-python