# Upload Video to GCP Cloud Storage in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mp4

I am trying to upload a video from my flutter client to my Node API. I am sending the file from the client as a stream which is being received by my server as an `application/octet-stream`.

How do I translate the octet-stream into .mp4 format on my server?

When I was just doing a `multipart/form-data` upload I had no problem uploading to GCP Storage in .mp4 format. But since the videos can get quick large I wanted to send it in chunks to my API.

Here is my current implementation:

```js
  const newFileName = 'newFile';
  const bucket = storage.bucket('dev.appspot.com');
  const blob = bucket.file(newFileName);
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
    contentType: 'video/mp4',
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'video/mp4',
    },
  });
  blobStream.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));
  blobStream.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('finished');
  });

  req.pipe(blobStream);
  req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('upload complete');
  });
```

**Update / Revision**

`req.pipe(blobStream);` did not work because I was piping the entire request body into CGS which was causing the issue.

I now have

```js
const newFileName = 'newFile';
          const bucket = storage.bucket('dev.appspot.com/postVideos');
          const blob = bucket.file(newFileName);
          const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
            metadata: { contentType: 'video/mp4' },
          });
          blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
          blobStream.on('finish', () => {
            resolve();
          });

          req.on('data', function(chunks) {
            // this is recieving video from the client in buffer chunks, but I have not figured out how to pipe those chunks into GCS as one file
          })
```

Now that I am recieving buffer chunks from the client, I am still unable to figure out how to stream those chunks into GCS to get one continuous file upload.

Comment: Does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666032/how-to-createwritestream-to-gcs) answer your question?

Comment: @jccampanero so I am able to create a writeStream to GCP when I send the whole file to my server at once. I am attempting to send a byte stream from my Flutter client to my API to then be processed in chunks which is where I run into my issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Storage: Setting incorrect MIME-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865486/google-cloud-storage-setting-incorrect-mime-type)