# Node.js Cloud Function - Stream CSV data directly to Google Cloud Storage file

Tags: node.js, upload, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a script that can call a RESTful API and retrieve CSV data from a report in chunks. I'm able to concatenate, parse, and display this data in the console. I am also able to write this CSV data to a local file and store it.

What I am trying to figure out is how to skip creating a file to store this data before uploading it to GCS and instead transfer it directly into Google Cloud Storage to save as a file. Since I am trying to make this a serverless cloud function, I am trying to stream it directly from memory into a Google Cloud Storage file.

I found this ['Streaming Transfers'](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) documentation on google, but it only references doing this with 'gsutil' and I am struggling to find any examples or documentation on how to do this with node.js. I also tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830163/node-js-stream-upload-directly-to-google-cloud-storage) on Stack overflow, but it's from 2013 and the methods seem a little out-dated. My script also isn't user-facing, so I don't need to hit any routes.

I am able to upload local files directly to my bucket using the function below, so Authentication isn't an issue. I'm just unsure how to convert a CSV blob or object in memory into a file in GCS. I haven't been able to find many examples so wasn't sure if anyone else has solved this issue in the past.

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId,
  keyFilename
 });

function uploadCSVToGCS() {
   const localFilePath = './test.csv';
   const bucketName = "Test_Bucket";
   const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

   bucket.upload(localFilePath);
};
```

I also found a 3rd party plugin that Google references called ['boto'](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin#streaming-transfers) that seems to do what I want, but this is for python, not node.js unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@doug-stevenson thanks for pushing me in the right direction. I was able to get it to work with the following code:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'test_bucket';
const blobName = 'test.csv';
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const blob = bucket.file(blobName);
const request = require('request');


function pipeCSVToGCS(redirectUrl) {
      request.get(redirectUrl)
      .pipe(blob.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
              contentType: 'text/csv'
          }
      }))
    .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error(`error occurred`);
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
        console.info(`success`);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Streaming object data to Cloud Storage is illustrated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage#upload_to_cloud_storage).  You will need to understand how [node streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) work, and make use of [createWriteStream](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream).  The sample code is not exactly what you want, but you'll use the same pattern:

```
function sendUploadToGCS (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return next();
  }

  const gcsname = Date.now() + req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    resumable: false
  });

  stream.on('error', (err) => {
    req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on('finish', () => {
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    file.makePublic().then(() => {
      req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);
      next();
    });
  });

  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this example still just sending pre-existing files submitted from a form though? The req in this example has a file within it right? I guess where I'm confused is how I serve the chunk of csv data returned from an API call into the 'createWriteStream' function. Do I just set it to the 'req.file' constant in my case?

Comment: If you have a stream for your source, you should just be able to pipe it into the write stream to Cloud Storage.  You will need to figure out what that source stream is.  I don't think there is any avoiding the need to understand how node streams work, as that's the vehicle to write the raw data of the object.