# Firebase Function & Storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Is it possible to create a JSON file from Cloud Function and save it to Cloud Storage? **Answer: Yes** if so How do we achieve that? **Answer: Using dataStream.pipe see below an example**

*dataStream.pipe example:*

```
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(Row);

  const stream = require('stream'),
    dataStream = new stream.PassThrough(),
    gcFile     = bucket.file("Leaderboard/users.json");

  dataStream.push(myJSON);
  dataStream.push(null);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dataStream.pipe(gcFile.createWriteStream({
        resumable  : false,
        validation : false,
        metadata   : {'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31536000'}
      }))
      .on('error', (error) => { 
        reject(error) 
      })
      .on('finish', () => { 
        resolve(true)
      })
  })
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is very broad, but your error message is very specific.  I suggest editing your question to focus on the error message rather than broad issues like "is it possible".  You will want to examine what specifically you're getting for the `storage` variable.

Comment: I have edited my question. in other words, what I want is to create a JSON file from my array on Cloud function and add it to the storage. From there on unity, i will get that JSON files.

Comment: I suggest removing your first question altogether and just focus on the code at hand.  "Is it possible" type questions are too broad and unspecific, as the answer is technically only "yes" or "no".  It's definitely possible to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: I changed my Question again :D

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my comments.  You've now made the question so broad that it's no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow.  You were better off showing the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explaining what it was supposed to, showing clearly where any errors are.  As I said, it **is** possible to do what you're saying, and you certainly had code started to make that work.  The issue is figuring out what the error message means, which Frank is helping you with in his answer.

Comment: broad? Doug, I just want to know if it's possible to create a JSON file from Cloud Function and save it to Cloud Storage? and if you tell me Yes Sebastien it is possible, then I want to know how to do it. I put back the code to show you how I try and fail to make a JSON file and save it to Cloud storage. Forget the error.

Comment: Why do you want to store JSON data in Cloud **Storage**? That's not what [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) is really for - you would be better off storing JSON data in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). Can you clarify what you're asking and what the use case is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `admin.storage()`, you are not using Firebase's regular JavaScript SDK for Storage, but actually the Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage. So the API is different, and it doesn't have a `ref()` function.

For some examples of how to upload a file using the Node.js SDK, see:

- [Upload files to Firebase Storage using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848132/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-using-node-js)
- [Upload file to google cloud storage with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919153/upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-with-nodejs)
- the documentation on [storing file uploads in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started#storing-file-uploads-in-cloud-storage)

Comment: Ok now that I have my bucket link, how do I upload a JSON file?

Comment: You call `upload` on the bucket, as shown in the first two links in my answer, and many more if you search for https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+a+file+to+cloud+storage+using+the+Node.js+SDK

Comment: Yeah, but how do we upload something that I did not store in my C:/ drive or elsewhere? the guy says `bucket.upload('Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt')` but I don't want to upload a local file. What I want is: Cloud function to create a JSON file then save it to the Storage. 
Sorry for my incompetence but I really need your help.

Comment: You can either write the data to the local disk first and use `upload`, or write it straight from memory as for example shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945376/how-to-upload-an-in-memory-file-data-to-google-cloud-storage-using-nodejs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927063/node-js-cloud-function-stream-csv-data-directly-to-google-cloud-storage-file (with an answer from Doug)